# Class method.. Print the monthly interest amount. Python

Tags: python

I am making a program that uses the class Account to print the monthly interest amount of accountA, among other things. I am having problems with getting the getMonthlyInterestRate() and getMonthlyInterest definitions to work out. Here is the program thus far:

Account.py

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self,id=0,balance=100.0,annualInterestRate=0.0):
        self.__id=id
        self.__balance=balance
        self.__annualInterestRate=annualInterestRate
    def getId(self):
        return self.__id
    def getBalance(self):
        return self.__balance
    def getAnnualInterest(self):
        return self.__annualInterestRate
    def setId(self,newid):
        self.__id=newid
    def setBalance(self,newbalance):
        self.__balance=newbalance
    def setAnnualInterestRate(self,newannualInterestRate):
        self.__annualInterestRate=newannualInterestRate
    def getMonthlyInterestRate(self,getAnnualInterest):
        return(getAnnualInterest(self)/12)
    def getMonthlyInterest(self,getBalance,getMonthly):
        return(getBalance(self)*getMonthlyInterestRate(self))

    def withdraw(self,amount):
        if(amount<=self.__balance):
            self.__balance=self.__balance-amount
    def deposit(self,amount):
        self.__balance=self.__balance+amount
    def __str__(self):
        return "Account ID : "+str(self.__id)+" Account Balance : "+str(self.__balance)+" Annual Interest Rate : "+str(self.__annualInterestRate)
```

next

file test.py

```
from Account import Account

def main():
    accountA=Account(0,100,0)
    accountA.setId(1234)
    accountA.setBalance(20500)
    accountA.setAnnualInterestRate(0.375)
    print(accountA.__str__())
    accountA.withdraw(500)
    accountA.deposit(1500)
    print(accountA.__str__())
    print(accountA.getMonthlyInterest(accountA.getBalance(),accountA.getAnnualInterest())) 
main()
```

I cannot figure out how to make the getMonthlyInterestRate() and getMonthlyInterest() defintions to work out to be able to put out the right output, which is:

```
Account ID :  1234 Account Balance :  20500 Annual Interest Rate :  0.375

Account ID :  1234 Account Balance :  21500 Annual Interest Rate :  0.375

Monthly Interest Amount :  671.875
```

mine always comes out with the error statement:

```
Account ID : 1234 Account Balance : 20500 Annual Interest Rate : 0.375
Account ID : 1234 Account Balance : 21500 Annual Interest Rate : 0.375
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 12, in main
  File "C:\Users\Meagan\Documents\University\2nd Year\Cmput 174\Account.py", line 21, in getMonthlyInterest
    return(getBalance(self)*getMonthlyInterestRate(self))
builtins.TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

this is what i should make:

- a method named getMonthlyInterestRate() that returns the monthly interest rate.
- a method named getMonthlyInterest() that return the monthly interest amount. The monthly interest amount can be calculated by using balance * monthly interest rate. The monthly interest rate can be computed by dividing the annual interest rate by 12.

everything else in the program is correct except for those two definitions and the last print statement. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to call `.__str__()` directly when printing; `print` will call it for you, so `print(accountA)` is enough.

Comment: There's also no need to call methods with `self`. It's done automagically...

Comment: It is not a function... a class function is a method

Comment: @foriinrangeawesome: Actually, `getBalance` _is_ a function, it's just that it's not in the right `locals` namespace. (This isn't quite true in 2.x, which has unbound methods, but the difference rarely matters; in 3.x it's literally true.) So, if you do `Account.getBalance(self)`, or `getBalance = self.__class__.getBalance; getBalance(self)`, or anything else to fix that problem, it will work exactly the same as `self.getBalance()` would. Of course just because you _can_ call it as a function instead of a bound method doesn't mean you _should_…

Comment: @Ben: It's only done automagically if you use method-calling syntax (so you get a bound method). Just `getBalance()` won't work; you need `self.getBalance()` (or `getBalance = self.getBalance; getBalance()` or something equivalent).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call methods *on* `self`, not by passing the functions around:

```
def getMonthlyInterest(self):
    return self.getBalance() * self.getMonthlyInterestRate()
```

and call it with:

```
print(accountA.getMonthlyInterest())
```

This goes for `getMonthlyInterestRate` as well:

```
def getMonthlyInterestRate(self):
    return self.getAnnualInterest() / 12
```

You use a lot of getters and setters; there is no need for these in Python; you don't need to make the attributes private, just access them directly instead:

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, id=0, balance=100.0, annualInterestRate=0.0):
        self.id = id
        self.balance = balance
        self.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate

    def getMonthlyInterestRate(self):
        return self.annualInterestRate / 12

    def getMonthlyInterest(self):
        return self.balance * self.getMonthlyInterestRate()

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if amount <= self.balance:
            self.balance -= amount

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount

    def __str__(self):
        return "Account ID : {0.id} Account Ballance : {0.balance} Annual Interest Rate : {0.annualInterestRate}".format(self)
```

then run:

```
def main():
    accountA = Account(0,100,0)
    accountA.id = 1234
    accountA.balance = 20500
    accountA.annualInterestRate = 0.375
    print(accountA)
    accountA.withdraw(500)
    accountA.deposit(1500)
    print(accountA)
    print(accountA.getMonthlyInterest())
```

Result:

```
Account ID : 1234 Account Ballance : 20500 Annual Interest Rate : 0.375
Account ID : 1234 Account Ballance : 21500 Annual Interest Rate : 0.375
671.875
```

Comment: The getters and setters were needed as part of our outline for the program. We are just learning this so they want to make sure we know all of the things. The attributes needed to private, as well. But thank you soooo much everyone for all of your help!!!! :) I just changed a couple things to make it work for the private attributes. `def getMonthlyInterestRate(self):
        return self.__annualInterestRate/12
    def getMonthlyInterest(self):
        return self.__balance*self.getMonthlyInterestRate()`

Answer (score 0):

You define

```
def getMonthlyInterestRate(self,getAnnualInterest):
    return(getAnnualInterest(self)/12)
def getMonthlyInterest(self,getBalance,getMonthly):
    return(getBalance(self)*getMonthlyInterestRate(self))
```

and use them as

```
print(accountA.getMonthlyInterest(accountA.getBalance(),accountA.getAnnualInterest()))
```

- in other words, you call them with the return values of the said functions, not with the functions themselves. Inside these functions, you try to call them again. As you didn't pass functions, but values, this "calling again" fails.

If you fix this bug, you (probably) make your program work, but youget a program written in very bad style.

To improve that, follow [Martijn Pieters's hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15797680/296974).

(This answer should probably have been a comment, but these cannot be formatted nicely.)